# A better way to build confidence bands around mean/median of an observed sample using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

So I have a three column data frame that has Trials, Ind. Variable, Observation. Something like:

`df1<- data.frame(Trial=rep(1:10,5), Variable=rep(1:5, each=10), Observation=rnorm(1:50))`

I am trying to plot a 95% conf. Interval around the mean for each trial using a rather inefficient method as follows:

```
    b<-NULL
    b$mean<- aggregate(Observation~Variable, data=df1,mean)[,2]
    b$sd  <- aggregate(Observation~Variable, data=df1,sd)[,2]
    b$Variable<- df1$Variable
    b$Observation <- df1$Observation 
    b$ucl <- rep(qnorm(.975, mean=b$mean, sd=b$sd), each=10)
    b$lcl <- rep(qnorm(.025, mean=b$mean, sd=b$sd), each=10)
    b<- as.data.frame(b)
    c <- ggplot(b, aes(Variable, Observation))  
    c + geom_point(color="red") + 
    geom_smooth(aes(ymin = lcl, ymax = ucl), data=b, stat="summary", fun.y="mean")
```

This is inefficient since it duplicates values for ymin, ymax. I've seen the geom_ribbon methods but I would still need to duplicate. However, if I was using any kind of smoothing like glm, the code is much simpler with no duplication. Is there a better way of doing this?

References:
 1. [R Plotting confidence bands with ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033551/r-plotting-confidence-bands-with-ggplot)
 2. [Shading confidence intervals manually with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463325/shading-confidence-intervals-manually-with-ggplot2)
 3. http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_smooth.html

Comment: It looks like your `variable` is discrete.  How about using boxplots?  Not exactly the same, but maybe good enough for your purposes?  Or is your real variable continuous?

Comment: @BrodieG: `Variable` unfortunately is continuous(100+ data-points), otherwise boxplot would have been perfect.

Comment: So do you wan the CI for a rolling bucket?  Or do you want the CI for each of the X values (assuming multiple instances of each X value)?

Comment: yes.. but NOT individual instances rather aggregate ones. I'm looking for CLs for each value of X regardless of the number of instances. If you try the code in the question it does that. I just thought there must be a `stat` or something more efficient.

Comment: I am even considering writing a small CI function and passing it to `summary` but haven't found a way that would make it work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With this method, I get the same output as with your method.  This was inspired by the [docs for ggplot](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/stat_summary.html).  Again, this will be meaningful so long as each `x` value has multiple points.

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(Trial=rep(1:10,5), Variable=rep(1:5, each=10), Observation=rnorm(1:50))    my_ci <- function(x) data.frame(y=mean(x), ymin=mean(x)-2*sd(x), ymax=mean(x)+2*sd(x))

my_ci <- function(x) data.frame(
  y=mean(x), 
  ymin=mean(x) - 2 * sd(x), 
  ymax=mean(x) + 2 * sd(x)
)
ggplot(df1, aes(Variable, Observation)) + geom_point(color="red") +
  stat_summary(fun.data="my_ci", geom="smooth")
```

[image]

Comment: :) just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 7):

The `ggplot` package comes with wrappers for a number of summarizing functions in the `Hmisc` package, including

1. `mean_cl_normal` which calculates the confidence limits based on the t-distribution,
2. `mean_cl_boot` which uses a bootstrap method that does not assume a distribution of the mean,
3. `mean_sdl` which uses a multiple of the standard deviation (default=2).

This latter method is the same as in the answer above, but is *not* the 95% CL. Confidence limits based on the t-distribution are given by:

> CL = t × s / √n

Where t is the appropriate quantile of the t-distribution and s is the sample standard deviation. Compare the confidence bands:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=Variable, y=Observation)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data="mean_sdl", geom="line", colour="blue")+
  stat_summary(fun.data="mean_sdl", mult=2, geom="errorbar", 
               width=0.1, linetype=2, colour="blue")+
  geom_point(color="red") +
  labs(title=expression(paste(bar(x)," \u00B1 ","2 * sd")))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=Variable, y=Observation)) + 
  geom_point(color="red") +
  stat_summary(fun.data="mean_cl_normal", geom="line", colour="blue")+
  stat_summary(fun.data="mean_cl_normal", conf.int=0.95, geom="errorbar", 
               width=0.1, linetype=2, colour="blue")+
  stat_summary(fun.data="mean_cl_normal", geom="point", size=3, 
               shape=1, colour="blue")+
  labs(title=expression(paste(bar(x)," \u00B1 ","t * sd / sqrt(n)")))
```

[image]

Finally, rotating this last plot using `coord_flip()` generates something very close to a `Forest Plot`, which is a standard method for summarizing data like yours.

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=Variable, y=Observation)) + 
  geom_point(color="red") +
  stat_summary(fun.data="mean_cl_normal", conf.int=0.95, geom="errorbar", 
               width=0.2, colour="blue")+
  stat_summary(fun.data="mean_cl_normal", geom="point", size=3, 
               shape=1, colour="blue")+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=mean(Observation)), linetype=2)+
  labs(title="Forest Plot")+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]